Places to harvest electromagnet coils
What are some common appliances or electronics that I can harvest a tightly wound coil and core from (like from a transformer for example)? I know about the dangers that come from messing with transformers. My goal is only to make a strong electromagnet so I'm only going to use one coil, not both. Also I'd preferably want one that can comfortably fit in the palm of you hand.

I recommend using a relay - 5 VDC (hobby), 12 VDC (auto) and 24 VDC (industrial) are very common.
For maximum holding capacity you want to have a U-shape as in a "horseshoe" magnet.

Figure 1. Image source Tabs Over Spaces.
Cut away the pivoting armature and contacts above the red line. You should be left with the flat steel armature on the left end and a circular pole piece coming up through the coil. They are connected in the base giving the horseshoe shaped armature discussed above.
The big advantage with this is that it's ready made, you know what voltage it's designed for and you shouldn't get smoke if you power it at the rated voltage.

I don't know much about relays, but since it just has to pull down a small metal bar, wouldn't that make it not a very strong electromagnet?

I never measured the force and the manufacturers won't quote them as they're irrelevant for the user. You should be able to do some calculations based on the coil power ($P = \frac {V^2} R $).
